# Improve Activity starting time (AsyncTask?)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have an Activity with a ViewPager and some Fragments in it.

The problem: It takes ages to start the activity because the ViewPager is created in the onResume methode. 2-3 seconds because of database requests.

I thought I can start a AsyncTask in onResume and do there the heavy work. But the time to start the Activity doesn't decrease.

If I place a Button in the View and do the work in onClick everything works fine. The Activity starts really fast and after the click the heavy work starts.

some code to think about:

The AsyncTask implementation

```
private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            PageAdapter mPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);

            return true;
        }

    }
```

the task is called in onResume

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        LoadTask task = new LoadTask();
        task.execute();
    }
```

This solution doesn't improve the starting time of the activity.

Is there a way to start the Activity and after inflating and displaying everything (progressbar...) doing the heavy task?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is setup the **empty** view pager and link it to the adapter when you create your activity.  Then, fill the content into whatever collection backs your adapter in the async task and notify the view that the dataset has changed.  The view can't be displayed until it's created and you have moved the registering of the adapter to the async task so you won't notice a difference.  The goal is to have your app show some view when you start it and simply fill in the data as it becomes available (as you probably know).

Comment: the ViewPager is empty at the beginning. It is created in the XML. But i can't see it. The ViewPager is filled with content by setting the PageAdapter into it. And that happens asyncronysly in the asynctask. But the entire acitvity is displaying after the asynctask ends. It's not clear to my why the Activity is not drawn while the asyncTask is doing things.

Comment: So you're saying if you comment out the async task altogether it works as expected (loads quickly) minus the pager being populated with legit data?  We might need some more code then.  Also, how much data are you trying to load and what are the specs of the system you're testing on?